# Does a bipartite, connected, acyclic graph with these conditions have a perfect matching?

Tags: graph-theory

As part of a larger proof, I'm trying to determine if there is necessarily a perfect matching for the graph $G$ with the following conditions:

1. $G$ is bipartite
2. $G$ is acyclic
3. $G$ is connected
4. $|V(G)|$ is even
5. $G$ has some matching $M$
6. $G$ has no $M$-augmenting paths
7. $|M| = \frac{|V(G)|}{2}$

Using [Berge's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berge%27s_lemma), we can tell that $M$ is a maximum matching, since there are no $M$-augmenting paths. I saw on this [Wolfram MathWorld page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PerfectMatching.html) that a graph has a perfect matching if its number of vertices is twice the size of its matching number (if I read correctly, this is the size of the maximum matching); assuming this page is correct, I think that would be sufficient to show that $G$ has a perfect matching. However, I can't find any other sources supporting this same claim.

Is there a way to prove $G$ has a perfect matching?

Comment: Since $G$ is acyclic and connected, $G$ is a tree, which has a perfect matching, I think.

Comment: @SimonShan I think that some trees don't have perfect matchings. For instance, a star graph $S_3$ (one vertex of degree 3, three vertices of degree 1).

Comment: I am wrong. Sorry about that. But, your graph has a matching $M$ with size $|V(G)|/2$, right?

Comment: Yes. In some simple examples I tried (along with the other conditions), it seems to make sense that this matching would be perfect. However, I haven't come up with or found a proof.

Comment: By the definition of matching, this matching with size $|V(G)|/2$ contains $|V(G)|$ distinct vertices, which implies it is a perfect matching.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks! Seems I overthought it.